# How can I display currency with decimal and without it in vue-i18n

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

With the following configuration I can output an amount with a currency

```
const numberFormats = {
    "en-GB": {
        currency: {
            style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP'
        }
    },
    "en-US": {
        currency: {
            style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'
        }
    }
}
```

inside a component

```
<p>{{ $n(100.20, 'currency') }}</p>
```

I can output:

```
<p>£100.20</p>
```

the following format can be fine on some cases but if I need to output simple amounts like: £5, £10 ect.. I cannot. I tried to configure it with no success.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `vue-i18n` [docs](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/en/number.html) indicates the number formats can include [`Intl.NumberFormat` options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat),  so you could set the `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` options both to zero in order to remove the decimal part from the currency.

You could define a new named format (e.g., "currencyNoCents") that uses these options:

```js
const numberFormats = {
  'en-US': {
    currency: {
      style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'
    },
    currencyNoCents: {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD',
      minimumFractionDigits: 0, // set fraction digits to 0 to remove cents
      maximumFractionDigits: 0
    }
  },
  'en-GB': {
    currency: {
      style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP'
    },
    currencyNoCents: {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'GBP',
      minimumFractionDigits: 0, // set fraction digits to 0 to remove cents
      maximumFractionDigits: 0
    }
  },
}

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en-GB',
  numberFormats
})

new Vue({
  i18n
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ $n(100.20, 'currency') }}</p>
  <p>{{ $n(100.20, 'currencyNoCents') }}</p>
</div>
```